# Break down Swift app into framewoks

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods

I am trying to break down a big swift project
into frameworks to cut down the compilation time
as explained here (http://bits.citrusbyte.com/improving-swift-compile-time/)

My app import a bunch of dependencies via cocoapods
and I am not really sure how I should proceed to break it down

This is what a simplified version of my app looks like right now

MyApp Podfile:

```
use_frameworks!
pod "SomeUIPod"
pod "SomeDataUtilsPod"
pod "SomeCommonUtilsPod"
```

I would like to break it down into three frameworks

- MyApp (depends on MyAppUtils, MyAppDataKitmin, SomeUIPod)
- MyAppDataKit (depends on MyAppUtils, SomeDataUtilsPod)
- MyAppUtils (depends on SomeCommonUtilsPod)

Any Idea how I could use cocoapod, and Cocoa touch framework to achieve that reorganization.

Comment: Are you asking whether or not you can mix and match CocoaPods and frameworks, or how to migrate your libraries to CocoaPods?

Comment: I am asking what the best way to make my app more modular by breaking it down into modules,  all my modules are private and will have dependencies on pods library, I dont really if I can achieve that by reorganizing my app into framework and somehow rewritting my Podfile to determine what deps go to which framework or if I need to write some kind of private cocoapods module and link all this modules to my app

Answer (score 0):

Well answering my own question here 
I found out that I could change the target membership of my Pod framework 
and associate it with my App but also any cocoa framework that I had inside my project, this let me build and split my app in frameworks and add any kind of pod dependency that I need